# Template variable not updating after scrollEvent in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an Ionic2 app. I am using **addScrollListener** event to update some variable and want to reflect that change in the Page view.

```
scrolledDistance:number = 0;
@ViewChild(Content) contentNew: Content;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.contentNew.addScrollListener(this.onPageScroll)
}

onPageScroll(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.scrolledDistance = event.target.scrollTop;    
          this.shouldShowFab = false;
          console.log("scrolld:::",this.scrolledDistance);
        }, 10)
}
```

and my Page is

```
<ion-item>
  {{scrolledDistance}}
</ion-item>
```

*scrolledDistance* variable is changing in console, but it is not reflected in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that inside the `onPageScroll(..)` method, the `this` keyword is not the component anymore, but the `window` object (that's why `this.scrolledDistance` is not the property on your component, but just a new property like `window.scrolledDistance`).

Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BiXbVX?p=preview) to see the solution. There, you can see that in order to avoid that from happening, you can declare the callback of the `addScrollListener` like this:

```
this.contentNew.addScrollListener((event) => 
  { 
    // here the this keyword refers to the component!! 
  });
```

So in this case it would look like:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.contentNew.addScrollListener((event) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.scrolledDistance = event.target.scrollTop;    
          this.shouldShowFab = false;
          console.log("scrolld:::",this.scrolledDistance);
        }, 10)
     });
  }
```

Comment: Ahhha, its a miracle. Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how you figure that out. My basics of core javascript are not that strong.

Comment: Mines aren't that strong either lol. My golden rule is: always when something seems not to be working properly, put a few `debugger` and inspect what the `this` is everywhere lol